# I can't get any indexOf() function to work for this code that I wrote

Tags: java, arrays, indexof

```java
package Captain_Ship.alphanum;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class A2N {
    public static String main(String input) {
        char[] alphabet = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y','z'};
        String output = "";
        char[] input_char = input.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        int[] output_int = {};

        //Still doesn't work. outputs [I@123772c4 in place of 8 5 12 12 15
        for (int i = 0; i>input_char.length; i++) {
            output_int[i] = ArrayUtils.indexOf(alphabet,input_char[i]);
        }
        output = Arrays.toString(output_int);
        return output;
    }
}
```

This is my code. It is super simple with its goal. Take a sentence and translate each letter into a number. So A would be 1, B would be 2, etc. I have tried everything to try and get the loop to work as I want it to. This piece of code is currently the only version which gave me something other than something similar to this: [I@123772c4. I have run out of the options I have researched.

Comment: `public static String main(String input) {`?

Comment: What's the problem, do you get 0 for a, 1 for b etc?

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions variabele names and method names should be written in camelCase, class names in PascalCase, and package names in all lowercase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for (int i = 0; i>input_char.length; i++) {` would never execute because `i` is never greater than `input_char.length` when initialized to `0`.

So change it to `for (int i = 0; i < input_char.length; i++) {`

And then initialize `output_int` to a char array of length equal to `input_char.length`.

`int[] output_int = new int[input_char.length]`.

Don't name your method `main`, although it compiles - never advisable. `main` is used as entry point of your application.

Comment: You got exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead of an array if you do not know the size of the array e.g. you do not know the size of `output_int` and therefore it's always better to use a dynamic array kind of object e.g. `List`.
2. You can use a `List` for storing the characters as well. `List` is part of Java collection API and this way you do not have to use a 3rd party library like `org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils` for operations like finding the index of an element.
3. Your loop should check `i < input_char.length` instead of `i > input_char.length` which will never be `true`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // List of alphabets
        List<Character> alphabet = List.of('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o',
                'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z');

        // A sample string
        String input = "sample string";

        char[] input_char = input.toLowerCase().toCharArray();

        // List to store the index of each character of `input` in `alphabet`. Note: if
        // a character is not found, the indexOf method returns -1
        List<Integer> output_int = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < input_char.length; i++) {
            output_int.add(alphabet.indexOf(input_char[i]));
        }

        // Display the list
        System.out.println(output_int);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[18, 0, 12, 15, 11, 4, -1, 18, 19, 17, 8, 13, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `indexOf()` method returns index of given character value or substring. If it is not found, it `returns -1`.

---

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    char[] alphabet = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};

    Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map = alphabetFrom0Index(alphabet);
//        printIndexAndLetters(alphabetFrom0Index(alphabet));

    String test = "Does it work";
    String test2 = "abc xyz";
    System.out.println(returnIndexNumbers(map, test));  // 15 5 19 9 20 23 15 18 11
    System.out.println(returnIndexNumbers(map, test2)); // 1 2 3 24 25 26

}

// return a string whit the index o letter from the alphabet from a map
public static String returnIndexNumbers(Map<Integer, String> map, String test) {
    // we create a stringBuilder for not creating every time a string
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    test.toLowerCase();
    // we iterate the string
    for (int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++) {
        // save the letter into a string from a char
        String letter = String.valueOf(test.charAt(i));

        // iterate over map, and if it match save the index to string
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if (letter.equals(entry.getValue())) {
                result.append(entry.getKey()+ " ");
            }
        }

    }
    // convert stringBuilder to a string. Wrapper
    return String.valueOf(result);
}


// for every character from the alphabet starting from 0
// we give them an index (0 - 25)
public static Map<Integer, String> alphabetFrom0Index(char[] alphabet) {
    // we defined a map that contains a pair of key-value
    // key is the index of the character & value is the character itself
    Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
        // i is the position of the character from the array
        // and i+1 to start from 1, and not from 0
        map.put(i+1, String.valueOf(alphabet[i]));
    }
    return map;
}

// print index and letter from a map
public static void printIndexAndLetters(Map<Integer, String> map) {
    map.entrySet().stream().forEach((Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry) -> {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
    });
}
```

}